# How can I get slug url in vue-router component and see product data?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I am building a vuejs app that uses an API to grab product data then renders it on the frontend. The site app is built in one js file with multiple components within the js file.

Technologies used:

**Vue 2**

**Vue Router**

**Vuex**

**Vue Resource(I know its depreciated for now)**

**The site for now is built on the shopify framework as we are leveraging some of their powerful features in the frontend.**

The very basic user journey is a user clicks on the product and they are taken to the url of that product where we have got a transition in vuejs to open the product and show details of it.

The way it gets the correct product is based on the id/order it is based in the list of products so the url structure is as follows:

`/products/:id` and the `id` can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc etc based on the order it is in the object list on the left in the screengrab below. Please see below for an idea of the structure:

[image]

As you can see the ids are on the far left.

Here is the code for this component below:

**Vuex store state**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
    products: [],
    productsAll: [],
    posts: [],
    pages: []
  },
  getters:{
    productsOrdered: state => {
      return _.orderBy(state.products, ['published_at'], ['desc']);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    addProducts (state, product) {
      state.products.push(product)
      state.productsAll.push(product)
    },
    addPosts (state, post) {
      state.products.push(post)
      state.posts.push(post)
    },
    addPages (state, page) {
      state.products.push(page)
      state.pages.push(page)
    }
  }
})
```

**The main product list component**
*Some methods have been removed to make code shorter*

```
const ListComp = {
props: ['products'],
    template: `
     <div id="start-grid" class="">

      <div class="grid__item-home no-padding" data-height="" v-for="(key, index) in productsOrderBy" :class="{ influence: productsOrderBy[index].influence === true, about: productsOrderBy[index].about === true, product_item: productsOrderBy[index].vendor}">

        <div v-if="productsOrderBy[index].vendor" class="shop-item">

          <router-link v-bind:data-id="productsOrderBy[index].id" :to="'/products/'+ productsOrderBy[index].handle" active-class="active" class="product grow">
            <div class="inner-container relative">
              <div class="pad-normal absolute top-0 left-0 z-2 large--one-whole product-color product-info">
                <h2 class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                  Shop
                 </h2>
                <p class="lyon-text">{{productsOrderBy[index].title}}</p>
                <p style="display: none;" class="lyon-text" v-html="productsOrderBy[index].body_html"></p>
                <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size buy">
                  Buy now
                 </p>
              </div>
              <div @click="setActive($event)" v-bind:data-id="productsOrderBy[index].id" class="z-1 relative gallery grow" v-bind:id="productsOrderBy[index].id">
                <img class="scale-with-grid archives-image" v-bind:src="productsOrderBy[index].images[0].src" v-bind:alt="productsOrderBy[index].images[0].id">
              </div>

            </div> 
            <transition 
                  v-if="$route.params.handle == productsOrderBy[index].handle"
                  appear
                  mode="out-in"
                  name="slide-fade">
                  <div class="absolute z-3 top-0 grid__item large--one-whole card">
                    <router-view :key="$route.params.id"></router-view>
                    </div>
                </transition>     
          </router-link>

        </div>

        <div v-else-if="productsOrderBy[index].about" :style="{ 'background-color': '+productsOrderBy[index].tags+' }" class="inner-container relative blog-index__block" :data-color="productsOrderBy[index].tags">

            <div @click="playVideo($event)" class="pad-normal z-1 large--one-whole">
                <h2 class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                  {{ productsOrderBy[index].title }}
                </h2>
                <p class="lyon-text" v-html="productsOrderBy[index].content.html">
                  {{ productsOrderBy[index].content.html }}
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div v-else class="inner-container relative blog-index__block" :data-color="productsOrderBy[index].tags">

              <div class="pad-normal z-1 large--one-whole">
                  <h2 class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                    Influence
                  </h2>
                  <p class="lyon-text">
                    {{ productsOrderBy[index].title }}
                  </p>
              </div>

              <img class="scale-with-grid archives-image" v-bind:src="productsOrderBy[index].media.image">

        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
    `, 
  data() {
    return {
        fade: true
    };
  },
  computed: {
    productsOrderBy() {
      //return this.store.getters.productsOrdered;
      return this.$store.getters.productsOrdered;
    },
    products() {
        return this.$store.state.products;
    },
    posts() {
      return this.$store.state.posts;
    }
  },
  methods: {

    initPackery() {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        packeryInit();
      }, 1000);
    },

    convertColour (element){

      setTimeout(function(){

        $('#start-grid .grid__item-home .blog-index__block').each(function(item){

          var _this = $(this);

          var blog_block = _this.data('color');
          $(_this).wrap('<div style="background-color:#'+_this.data('color')+';"></div>');

          //console.log(_this);

        });

      }, 1000);

    },

    unsetActive(event){

      $('div').removeClass('inactive is-active');

    },

    scrollToAnchor() {

        $('#app').velocity('scroll', {
            duration: 50,
            offset: 0,
            easing: 'ease-in-out'
        });

    },


  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.initPackery();
    this.convertColour();
    this.unsetActive();
    this.scrollToAnchor();
  }
};
```

**The product detail component**

```
const DetailsComp = {
    props: ['handle','id','productsOrdered'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        baseCost:[],
        slickOptions: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          dots: true,
          adaptiveHeight: false,
          infinite: true,
          centerMode: false,
          focusOnSelect: true,
          speed: 700,
          useTransform: true,
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          prevArrow: '.prev-slider',
          nextArrow: '.next-slider',
          responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 980,
                settings: {
                  variableWidth: true,
                  slidesToShow: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 769,
                settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 1,
                  dots: true,
                  arrows: false,
                  centerPadding: '0px',
                  variableWidth: false,
                  adaptiveHeight: false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 1,
                  dots: true,
                  arrows: false,
                  centerPadding: '0px',
                  variableWidth: false,
                  adaptiveHeight: false
                }
            }
          ]
        },
        params: {
          title: this.$store.getters.productsOrdered[this.id || this.$route.meta.defaultId],
          description: 'website description'      
        },
      }
    },
    components: { 'slick': Slick }, 
    template: `
        <div class="product-main">

        <a href="#" @onclick="prev" class="slider-arrows prev-slider"></a>

          <slick class="z-1 relative slider" ref="slick" v-bind:id="product.id" :options="slickOptions">
            <div v-for="image in product.images">

              <img class="scale-with-grid archives-image" v-bind:src="image.src" v-bind:alt="image.id">

            </div>
          </slick>

        <a href="#" @onclick="next" class="slider-arrows next-slider"></a>


        <form @submit.prevent="add()" data-cart-submit="data-cart-submit">
          <div class="pad-normal relative">

            <div class="close-button selected"><router-link v-on:click.native="unsetActive($event)" v-bind:data-id="product.id" :to="'/'"><span></span><span></span></router-link></div>

            <div class="product-title">
              <h5 class="lyon-text">{{product.title}}, <span class="js-cost" v-for="variant in product.variants" v-if="variant.position == 1">£{{ variant.price }}</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="product-description">
              <p class="univers uppercase body-size">Description</p>
              <p class="lyon-text" v-html="product.body_html"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid__item large--one-half medium--one-half small--one-whole size">
              <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">size</p>
              <select name="id" class="productSelect univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                <option v-for="variant in product.variants" v-bind:data-sku="variant.sku" v-bind:data-price="variant.price" v-bind:value="variant.id">{{ variant.title }}</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="grid__item large--one-half medium--one-half small--one-whole size js-qty univers uppercase smaller body-size">
              <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">quantity</p>
              <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector univers uppercase smaller body-size">
            </div>

            <button v-on:click="add" type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn addToCartButton">
              <span id="AddToCartText" class="univers uppercase smaller body-size text-black">Add to bag</span>
            </button>   
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    `,
    computed: {
        product() {
        return this.$store.getters.productsOrdered[this.id || this.id];
      }
    },
    mounted: function() {

      this.setParentHeight();

    },
    methods: {
      add: function (event) {

        var selectedOption = [],
            _this = event.target;

        $('.productSelect').find('option:selected').each(function(){                    
          selectedOption.push($(this).val());                
        });

        var qty = $('.js-qty input').val();

        if (selectedOption) {
          CartJS.addItem(selectedOption, qty);
        }

        var z = document.createElement('div');
        z.innerHTML = '<p style="text-align: center;margin: 20px 0;" class="univers uppercase smaller body-size text-black feedback">Product added</p>';
        _this.parentNode.appendChild(z);

      },
      setParentHeight(){
          if($(window).width() <= 599 && mobile_device) {
            $('.product.active .card').css('height',$('.product.active .card').find('.product-main').outerHeight(true));
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            $('.grid__item-home.is-active').css('height',$('.product.active .card').find('.product-main').outerHeight(true));
          }
      },
      unsetActive(event){

        $('div').removeClass('inactive is-active');
        $('.grid__item-home').css('height','auto');

      },

      next() {
          this.$refs.slick.next();
      },
      prev() {
          this.$refs.slick.prev();
      }

    }

};
```

I am trying to achieve the following with the above and that is a user clicks on the product and you see a url like:

`/products/a-product-handle-from-the-api-object`

Hopefully someone can shed light onto what might do the trick here.